# literal for int() with base 10: 'testuser' even tho the argument passed is a string

Tags: python, django

I have to make a project blog for my college assignment and am trying to make a page to display all the posts by a particular user but I keep getting this error

> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/home/Grayocean/grayocean.co/blog/views.py" in user_blog_list
>     121.    blogs=get_object_or_404(Blog, author=username)
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py"
>   in get_object_or_404
>     93.         return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in get
>     399.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in filter
>     892.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py"
>   in _filter_or_exclude
>     910.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in add_q
>     1290.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in _add_q
>     1318.                     split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in build_filter
>     1251.         condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py"
>   in build_lookup
>     1116.         lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py"
>   in **init**
>     20.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_lookups.py"
>   in get_prep_lookup
>     115.                 self.rhs = target_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
>
> File
>   "/home/Grayocean/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py"
>   in get_prep_value
>     966.         return int(value)
>
> Exception Type: ValueError at /user/rheazes Exception Value: invalid
>   literal for int() with base 10: 'testuser'

views.py

```
def user_blog_list(self, username):
    blogs=get_object_or_404(Blog, author=username)
    context={
    'posts':blogs
    }
    return render(request,'blog/user_posts.html',context)
```

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content=models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images', blank=True)
    image1= models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images', blank=True,verbose_name='second image')
    image2= models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images', blank=True,verbose_name='third image')
    image3= models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images', blank=True,verbose_name='fourth image')
    image4= models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_images', blank=True,verbose_name='fifth image')
    video =models.FileField(upload_to='blog_images',blank=True)
    date_posted=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='likes',blank=True)
    dislikes=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='dislikes',blank=True)
```

urls.py

```
path('user/<str:username>',views.user_blog_list,name='user-posts'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using the ***wrong lookup expression*** in the **`get_object_or_404()`** function. It should be **`author__username=username`** instead of **`author=username`**

```
def user_blog_list(self, username):
    blogs=get_object_or_404(Blog, author__username=username) # change is here <<<<
    context={
    'posts':blogs
    }
    return render(request,'blog/user_posts.html',context)
```